# Handlebars & Jquery: Dynamically generated ids

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

I am generating a dynamic `form` and `button` on a `handlebars` page.

The original `handlebars` code is this:

```
{{#each record}}
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="comment" value={{comment}}> 
    <button class="btn small btn-success" id="btn-savecomment">SAVE COMMENT</button>
{{/each}}
```

and I have a jquery script to save the contents of the form when each button is pressed:

```
$(document).ready (
    function() {
        $(document).on('click','#savecomment',function(event){
            // save id: comment to record
    );
```

The purpose is to allow the user to type in a comment and then save it to each record.

However how can I ensure the button identifies the right input form when looking the comment? When I click on a particular button it only retrieves the comment from the first record because all of them have identical ids.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could dynamically generate the IDs, but most likely you should just should just be using classes or data-values (or similar) that are a better fit:

```
{{#each record}}
    <input class="form-control" type="text" data-comment={{@index}} value={{comment}}> 
    <button class="btn small btn-success" data-trigger="save">SAVE COMMENT</button>
{{/each}} 

$(document).on("click", "[data-trigger='save']", function (evt) {
  var commentID = $(this).prev().data("comment"); //index number, can be pretty much anything
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not have identical id on different element. That's why your code isn't working. Give each element a different id.
You may use `{{@index}}` to get the current iteration count and then use it in the id to generate a dynamic id i.e:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="comment_{{@index}}" value={{comment}}>
```

You should do the same for the button as well. In your jQuery code, you can then access the input using `prev()` method

You can then access it using jquery. Or you may also use class instead of id. That would be better.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is actually wrong. As you know already, `ID`s should not be duplicated. You should be using something like this:

```
{{#each record}}
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="comment" value={{comment}}> 
    <button class="btn small btn-success btn-savecomment" id="btn-savecomment-{{@index}}">SAVE COMMENT</button>
{{/each}}
```

And the next one is in the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-savecomment', function (event) {
        // save id: comment to record
    });
});
```

Comment: There's an ID-field on the `<input>` too that would need to be incremented.