# Handlebars and node problem getting dynamic list id

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, handlebars.js

I created a for using handlebars to get the values ​​from my bank, the search is coming correctly but when trying to select one of the city options it returns me undefined

I believe it is something in this style, but could not apply in my code

[Handlebars & Jquery: Dynamically generated ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166258/handlebars-jquery-dynamically-generated-ids)

```
    $(document).on("click", "[data-trigger='save']", function (evt) {var commentID = $(this).prev().data("comment");});


 {{#each cidade}}
   <div class="card mt-4">
     <label for="bott"><button class="btn" name="cid" id="cid" data-trigger="save">
       <div class="card-body">
          <small>{{estado}} - {{ativo}} </small>
             <input type="hidden" data-comment ="{{@index}}" name="idcid" id="idcid" value="{{_id}}">
                  </div>
                      </button>
                          </label>
                            </div> 
                                  {{else}}
                                    <h4 value="0">Nenhuma cidade registrada</h4>
                                    {{/each}}

         <input type="text" id="cidade" name="cidade" class="form-control" disabled>
```

The question is to take the id value and the name of the selected button and put the related name in the input text
If you need to add information let me know because I'm new here and I'm using google translator for this conversation
thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page  Don't repeat ids.  Use classes with contextual lookups.

Comment: can you give me an example of how not to repeat ids since my list is dynamic

Comment: Change `id="whatever"` that you have to `class="whatever"` and you no longer repeat ids.  Then use https://api.jquery.com/closest to find the contextual parent of both the elements you are concerned with, then https://api.jquery.com/find the other element you want to change, and change it.